# Mi intención es generar un consecutivo que se llene automaticamente, sin embargo al momento de ejecutar el codigo me sale el siguiente error

Tags: excel, macros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim fila, final As Long
    'Blancos
    fila = 2
    Do While Hoja2.Cells(fila, 1) <> ""
    fila = fila + 1
    Loop
    final = final - 1
    Hoja2.Cells(fila, 1) = item
    
    'Aumentar
    fila = 2
    Do While Hoja2.Cells(fila, 1) <> ""
    fila = fila + 1
    Loop
    final = final - 1
    If Hoja2.Cells(2, 1) = Empty Then
    item = 0 + 1
    Else
    item = Hoja2.Cells(final, 1) + 1
    End If
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Por cierto: título => resumen del problema, cuerpo => descripción del problema. ¡No coloques el cuerpo en el título! Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Tu variable  `final` no está inicializada y le estás restando 1. Si llega a `Hoja2.Cells(final,1)` vas a tener problemas.